# (1/1) BadMethodCallException in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've set up a simple controller, route and a view in my new installation of Laravel 5.4.

Here's my web.php:

```
<?php
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('profile', 'UserController@profile');
```

My UserController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function profile()
    {
        return view('profile'); 
    }

}
```

My view file is profile.blade.php and there is one string only "Hello world!"

When trying to access: *.*.*.*/profile i get

> ```
> (1/1) BadMethodCallException
> Method [profile] does not exist.
> in Controller.php (line 82)
> at Controller->__call('profile', array())
> at UserController->profile()
> at call_user_func_array(array(object(UserController), 'profile'), array())
> in Controller.php (line 55)
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me to understand

Comment: did you create any other folder to keep your controllers...inside http/Cotrollers.?

Comment: @molagbal no i have not created any additional folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that route can not find the controller.Or project files are messed up.

Go ahead and delete the controller.Then run `composer dump-autoload`

Then run the command on command line `php artisan make:controller UserController` then paste profile method that u have.

Comment: I dont really understand what was wrong but that did it. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand it at all either, but this worked for me too. The issue started when I upgraded from L5.3 to 5.4 and the userController was the only controller Laravel was seemingly unable to read. I would +1000 if I could! Well done sir!